# Trouble with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a functional autocomplete, however when I fill in the data it shows me the name to select, but when I select it ... it stores the ID of that name that I selected.
In the database the value to save is the ID of that name selected, but is there any way it can fill me in with the name and store the ID in the database?

for example, I selected a name, but it shows me the ID and not the name, as shown in the image. Is it possible that he shows me the name and just keeps the ID?

[image]

**Model**

```
public partial class Filho
    {
        public int ID_Filho { get; set; }
        public int ID_Utilizador { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Morada { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataRegisto { get; set; }
        public int ID_Sala { get; set; }

        public virtual Utilizador Utilizador { get; set; }
        public virtual Sala Sala { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
 {
     ClassEntities entities = new ClassEntities();
     var pais = (from Utilizador in entities.Utilizador
                     where Utilizador.NomeUtilizador.StartsWith(prefix)
                     select new
                     {
                         label = Utilizador.NomeUtilizador,
                         val = Utilizador.ID_Utilizador
                     }).ToList();   
     return Json(pais);
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <span class="label-input100">NAME</span>
    <input class="input100" type="text" id="txtUtilizador" name="ID_Utilizador">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $("#txtUtilizador").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/Filhos/AutoComplete/',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.val,
                            };
                        }))
                    }
                })
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Method**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ID_Utilizador = new SelectList(db.Utilizador, "ID_Utilizador", "NomeUtilizador");
    ViewBag.ID_Sala = new SelectList(db.Sala, "ID_Sala", "NomeSala");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID_Filho,ID_Utilizador,Nome,Morada,DataNascimento,DataRegisto,ID_Sala")] Filho filho)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Filho.Add(filho);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ID_Utilizador = new SelectList(db.Utilizador, "ID_Utilizador", "NomeUtilizador", filho.ID_Utilizador);
    ViewBag.ID_Sala = new SelectList(db.Sala, "ID_Sala", "NomeSala", filho.ID_Sala);
    return View(filho);
}
```

Comment: there is also an `id` attribute in jquery autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add a hidden field with name to keep value when submit form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID_Utilizador"/>
```

Implement select method, comment out custom mapping

```
select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            $("[name='ID_Utilizador']").val(ui.item.value);

        }
```

This is html for page

```
<div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <span class="label-input100">NAME</span>
    <input class="input100" type="text" id="txtUtilizador">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID_Utilizador"/>
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#txtUtilizador").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/Filhos/AutoComplete/',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        //    return {
                        //        label: item.label,
                        //        value: item.val,
                        //        id : item.val
                        //    };
                        //}))
                        response(data);
                    }
                })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            $("[name='ID_Utilizador']").val(ui.item.value);

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: if not saving to DB, please post your form here and action post method

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but it's not working. It does not save in the database. I already added the model and have the controller

Comment: Please check value of hidden field I added

Comment: Did not entry in the cycle if

Comment: Did you add input hidden and select method with set value for hidden field? F12 to check hidden field value before submit

Comment: I discovered the error,  $("[name='ID_Utilizador']").val(ui.item.val);